# Descriptive explanation of different Carbon Nanotubes Conductivity

Tags: organic-chemistry, conductivity

I'm soon having a talk about Carbon Nanotube FETs and wanted to give a short introduction into CNTs in general. Of course for device operation it's important that some types of single-walled CNTs are conductive while others behave more like a semiconductor. Since the talk should not be very long I don't want to dive into the tight binding calculations. So I want to know if there is a more picturesque (even if not fully correct or detailed) way of explaining the different band structures of zigzag, armchair and chiral Carbon Nanotubes. Maybe via orbital overlap or something?

Thanks in advance!